# Convert from MySQL query using SUBSTRING_INDEX into Joomla API query?

Tags: joomla-3.4, mysql

I have a query which gets the information that I want using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in MySQL. I am trying to convert this to use the Joomla query building syntax, but I am not sure how it should be formatted?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`file_url`, '/', -1), ".", 1),"-",1) AS product_sku, `virtuemart_media_id`, `virtuemart_product_id` FROM `jos_virtuemart_medias` INNER JOIN `jos_virtuemart_products` ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`jos_virtuemart_medias`.`file_url`, '/', -1), ".", 1),"-",1) = `jos_virtuemart_products`.`product_sku` WHERE 1
```

I'm getting stuck at the first hurdle as I really can't figure out how to implement the SELECT statement?

Any advise would be most appreciated? I have had a look at the Joomla docs, but it doesn't cover the inclusion of MySQL functions.

Comment: sometime it's easier to just use regular SQL like you did and use $db->setQuery($query). I'm not sure you can do that with the SQL Joomla API

Comment: @Pierre-AndréVullioud thank you. Are you able to help me convert the select into an insert statement? Im struggling to understand it due to the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try {
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select("b.product_sku, a.virtuemart_media_id, a.virtuemart_product_id")
                ->from("#__virtuemart_medias a")
                ->innerJoin("#__virtuemart_products b ON a.SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.file_url, '/', -1), '.', 1), '-', 1) = b.product_sku");
    $db->setQuery($query);
    if (!$results = $db->loadAssocList()) {
        echo "No Qualifying Results";
    } else {
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Product SKU</th>";
                echo "<th>Media ID</th>";
                echo "<th>Product ID</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            foreach ($results as $row) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>{$row['product_sku']}</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$row['virtuemart_media_id']}</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$row['virtuemart_product_id']}</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Syntax Error";
    // echo $query->dump();    // don't show actual details to the public
    // echo $e->getMessage();  // don't show actual details to the public
}
```

- Full disclosure: I've never used virtuemart; I don't know if these columns exist or if this query logic will be successful.  I am merely converting your posted query.
- Because `product_sku` in your JOIN contains your desired `file_url` substring, we'll just use that table's column value to avoid that nasty triple-`SUBSTRING_INDEX()` call in the `SELECT` clause.
- By assigning table aliases (`a` & `b`) you can reduce query bloat.
- I don't know if there is a cleaner way to isolate the `file_url` substring because I don't know what format that data is in -- I must say it looks rather heavy-handed though.